# my checkbox (material-ui) is not disabling

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui

I created a checkbox below, but it is not working enabled disabled, could you help me?

sorry, I misexpressed myself, my checkbox is not ticking and unchecking.

```
<Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
            <FormControlLabel
              control={
                <Checkbox
                  checked={state.checkedB}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  name="isVirtual"
                  color="primary"
                />
              }
              label="Criar Link de Reunião (Google Meeting)"
          />
```

I have two useState in one, I don't know if that's correct either.

```
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    checkedA: true,
    checkedB: true,
    checkedF: true,
    checkedG: true,
  });

  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setState({ ...!state, [event.target.name]: event.target.checked });
    setPersonName(event.target.value);
  };
```

I'm using material-ui.

Comment: Where do you attempt to set the `disabled` property on the `<Checkbox>`?  What isn't working in that attempt?

Comment: sorry, I misexpressed myself, my checkbox is not ticking and unchecking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the material ui docs page for checkbox components (https://material-ui.com/api/checkbox/#checkbox-api)

It lists the `disabled` attribute

> | Name | Type | Default | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | disabled | bool |  | If true, the checkbox will be disabled |

You can use that to disable the checkbox and prevent it from triggering the `onClick` function

```js
<Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
  <FormControlLabel
    control={
      <Checkbox
        checked={state.checkedB}
        onChange={handleChange}
        name="isVirtual"
        color="primary"
    
        disabled
      />
    }
    label="Criar Link de Reunião (Google Meeting)"
  />
</Grid>;
```

Comment: sorry, I misexpressed myself, my checkbox is not ticking and unchecking.